# Loop That Doesn't End Until Break

Tags: objective-c, xcode, loops

I'm trying to create a loop than continues to take input until the input gives the command to break the loop. What I'm doing now looks a little like this:

```
int start = 1;

while (start == 1) {

   //Program statement

}
```

However, I feel as though there is an easier, more effective way to create a loop that repeats until the user gives the command to stop it. Does something like that exist?

Comment: The way you have this now is fine, although usually the variable would be called `continue`, or else `stop` with the test reversed: `BOOL stop = NO; while( !stop ){ //... };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common idiom to express a "forever" loop in C and other C-like languages, including Objective-C, is to use an empty `for`:

```
for(;;) {
    // statements
}
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I wanted! Thank you

Comment: `while(1)` is pretty common, too.

Comment: @rickster True, although `for (;;)` was suggested in K&R (top of the page 54 in the second edition).

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
while(true)
{
    if( exit_condition)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have, unless true is a valid undeclared condition

Answer (score 1):

```
do{

   userInput = readUserInput()

}while(userInput != exit_condition)
```

Any loop as for, while, or even goto can do this job. If you put a condition instead of "true" in the loop, You can reduce code and doesn't need to use the "break" statement.

Comment: do{ userInput = readUserInput() }while(user_input != exit_condition) will work then